# How to select all records from a table that does not exist in another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table A with columns `key` and `date`, and table B with columns `key`, `date`, and `flag`. I'd like to select all records from A where if the keys and dates match with B, B's flag is false, as well as select records from A where the keys and dates do not match.

The keys repeat - once per date. Edited to add that A could also contain key-date pairs not existing in B, which I want in the result. For example,

if A is

| Key | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/2020 |
| 1 | 2/2020 |
| 2 | 1/2020 |
| 2 | 2/2020 |
| 2 | 3/2020 |
| 3 | 1/2020 |
| 3 | 2/2020 |

if B is

| Key | Date | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/2020 | True |
| 1 | 2/2020 | True |
| 2 | 1/2020 | True |
| 2 | 2/2020 | False |
| 2 | 3/2020 | False |

then I'd like the result to be

| Key | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2/2020 |
| 2 | 3/2020 |
| 3 | 1/2020 |
| 3 | 2/2020 |

Here's what I came up with:

```
SELECT key
FROM A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM B 
     WHERE A.date= B.date
     AND B.flag = TRUE)
```

Does the code look right? Is there a faster query using NOT IN or EXCEPT?

Comment: You are missing `A.key = B.key` in the subquery conditions. (And the date in the main `SELECT` clause.) Then, yes this approach is good. `NOT IN` is just as good, as long as there are no nulls involved and the DBMS can handle tuples with the `IN` clause. And `EXCEPT` is also equally good. Choose whatever works and what you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the code look right?

No, it will select records from A that don't have corresponding entries in B at all.

Use this:

```
SELECT  key, date
FROM    a
INTERSECT
SELECT  key, date
FROM    b
WHERE   flag IS DISTINCT FROM true -- handles NULL values as well
```

This assumes that you only need key and date from A, and they are unique.

If you need other fields, or if (key, date) are not unique in A, use this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    a
WHERE   (key, date) IN
        (
        SELECT  key, date
        FROM    b
        WHERE   flag IS DISTINCT FROM true
        )
```

##### Update after a substantial requirements change:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    a
WHERE   (key, date) NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  key, date
        FROM    b
        WHERE   flag -- if key and date are both not nullable
        )
```

or

```
SELECT  *
FROM    a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT
        FROM    b
        WHERE   (b.key, b.date, b.flag) = (a.key, a.date, true)
        )
```

Comment: There are more cols I want from A. There are no null values for flag. For table A, there could be a key-date pair that doesn't exist in B, such as key=3 and date=1/2020, and I would like to keep that in the result (edited the question to add this info). In that case, could I use your 2nd query, but change IN to NOT IN, and change the WHERE clause to flag=TRUE?

Comment: @user1729870: "all records from A where the keys and dates match with B's": please fix it